# YouTube API v3 not returning items/channel id

Tags: python, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've desperately searched online and on SO for an answer to this question - but none of the answers have been helpful or simply remain unanswered (which I find happens often with API questions).

In order for my scraper to run I read in a "User ID" which then fetches the "Channel ID" using the YouTube API.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key={API_KEY}&forUsername={USER_ID}&part=id
```

Returns:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"3WIcRE7IJ70nCYemJJIi1L7dYAg/6uvK8IjShzZ17Ahyr1FaURwOhkM\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": []
}
```

In which the "items" section usually contains the Channel ID I need in order to run my program.

This particular page is a "daughter" page of a larger network (think individual country pages for a global brand). Would this be the reason the channel id is missing?

Is there any other way to find the channel id (without being the owner of the page)? Why is this channel's id missing?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

And of course I find it 2 minutes after I ask my question:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q={USER_ID}&type=channel&key={API_KEY}
```